# Applying an operator to a wavefunction vs. a (ket) vector

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction, notation

I have a question regarding the effect of quantum mechanical operators. The definition that I'm familiar with says that an operator $A$ acts on a vector from a Hilbert space, $|\psi\rangle$, and the result is another vector, $|\psi'\rangle$:
$$A |\psi\rangle = |\psi'\rangle.$$

However, in class I've also seen operators applied to scalar-valued functions, such as the momentum operator in position space:
$$P = - i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x},\quad P \psi(x) = - i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \psi(x)$$

However, mathematically, that doesn't make sense to me, since $P$ should operate on a vector, not a (scalar) function! I know that wave functions can be viewed as the coefficients of a state vector when the vector is written in a particular basis, such as
$$|\psi\rangle
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty |x\rangle \langle x| \,\mathrm{d}x\; |\psi\rangle
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty |x\rangle \langle x|\psi\rangle \,\mathrm{d}x
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi(x) |x\rangle  \,\mathrm{d}x$$
with
$$\psi(x) = \langle x|\psi\rangle$$
but, as far as I can tell, the operator should still act on a vector, not on a function alone.

On the Wikipedia article "[Operator (physics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_%28physics%29#Linear_operators_in_wave_mechanics)", under "Linear operators in wave mechanics", I found the following:

> $$A \psi(x) = A \langle x | \psi \rangle = \langle x | A | \psi \rangle$$

However, that last step seems dubious to me. Is it valid to just swap the operator into the inner product like that? In general, I don't see the mathematical meaning of expressions like $A\psi(x)$ or $A \langle x|$, since $A$ can neither act on a scalar value nor on a bra. Does it only work for self-adjoint operators, since we'd then have $A^\dagger = A$, which might help with $A$ acting on bras?

Comment: Briefly, $\psi(x)$ is to $|\psi \rangle$ as $v^i$ is to $\vec v$.  The former are the *components* of the vector (on some basis) and the later is the vector proper.  Similarly, there are the matrix elements of an operator (on some basis) and the operator proper.  Operating on the components of a vector with the matrix representation of an operator, even when the components and matrix elements are continuous functions, is not particularly mysterious if you think about it a bit.

Comment: $A \psi (x)$ means working in coordinate representation, $$ A \psi (x):= \langle x | \hat{A} | \psi \rangle$$.

Comment: @user26143 This is similar to the comment I posted on Trimok's answer, but your comment creates the same question for me:

Does that mean that the example I quoted from Wikipedia is incorrect? After all, with your definition, that would mean
$$A \psi(x)
= \langle x | A | \psi \rangle
\ne A \langle x | \psi \rangle$$

That last expression doesn't make mathematical sense to me to begin with. Am I correct with this?

Comment: For me, abstract operator acts on abstract vector. It's not clear to me what does $A \langle x | \psi \rangle$ mean. It may mean regarding $\langle x | \psi \rangle$ as a $c$-number , then $A \langle x | \psi \rangle = \langle x | \psi \rangle A$, which seems *not* the wiki suppose to say.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your confusion stems from the fast that this is a mixture of abuse of notation and having different Hilbert spaces to work with:

Generally the abstract operator $A$ acts on some abstract vector $|\psi\rangle$, for example the momentum operator $\hat p$ acts on its eigenstates $|p\rangle$ by $\hat p |p \rangle = p |p \rangle$.

In the wavefunction formalism, we say that for a Hilbert space that has some position basis $|x\rangle$, we can switch to the space of square-integrable functions $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ without loss of information by defining $\psi(x) = \langle x | \psi \rangle $. This $\psi(x)$ now is a scalar function, *and* it is a vector as an element of the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Now, operators on this Hilbert space must be operators on the functions, and it just so hpapens that the explicit form of the momentum operator is $\hat p = \mathrm{i}\hbar \partial_x $. This can be seen by considering the momentum operator as the generator of translations as per $T(\delta x) = 1 - \frac{\mathrm{i}}{\hbar}\hat p \delta x $ which must act as $T(\delta x) |x\rangle = |x + \delta x\rangle$ and then appying this to some $|\psi\rangle$. Let me know if you wish me to carry out that (not overly long) calculation.

Your comments have made it clearer to me what you actually want, the following is intended to address that:

In general, the kets $|\psi\rangle$ are elements of an abstract Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, we know nothing more about them.

In the context we are discussing, $\mathcal{H}$ is the space of states of a particle moving in one dimension, which we will call $\mathcal{H}_{1D}$. It is constructed by saying that there is an operator $\hat x$ on $\mathcal{H}_{1D}$ and a set of states $X := \{|x\rangle | x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ which are the eigenvectors of $\hat x$, i.e $\hat x | x \rangle = x | x \rangle\forall |x\rangle \in X$, and demanding that $X$ is a basis of $\mathcal{H}_{1D}$, where "basis" means a "rigged basis" as  also explained in [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/359982/50583). In the following, none of the integrals and manipulations involving $\lvert x \rangle$ are fully mathematically rigorous.

Now, consider the Hilbert space of square integrable functions $ f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $, denoted $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$. To every function $ \psi :\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ with $\psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$, we define
the map
$$ \mathrm{Ket}: L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_{1D}, \psi \mapsto|\psi\rangle := \int_{-\infty}^\infty\psi(x)|x\rangle\mathrm{d}x,$$
where the integral is *supposed* to be a generalization of the usual basis decomposition $\sum_n c_n \vert n\rangle$ for a countable basis and should probably be some sort of [Bochner integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral), yet the space the $\lvert x\rangle$ live in is unfortunately not a Banach space, so this does not work straightforwardly.

Certainly, different functions $\psi,\psi'$ cannot generate the same ket this way, since for $\psi \neq \psi'$, we must have $\psi(x_0) \neq \psi'(x_0)$ at some $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, so the generated kets will differ, since the coefficient of at least one basis ket differs between them. Thus, this map is injective, and no information is lost.

Conversely, for a given ket $|\psi\rangle$ define the map

$$ \mathrm{Func} : \mathcal{H}_{1D} \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}), |\psi\rangle\mapsto (\psi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, x \mapsto \langle x | \psi \rangle)$$

Ignoring that fact that the $\psi$ here is not always really a function, but belongs to the larger space of tempered distributions containing $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$, we can again see that different kets cannot produce the same function $\psi$, since $\langle x | \psi\rangle$ gives the coefficents in the basis $X$, and two vectors with identical basis coefficents are identical. Thus, this map is also injective, and so also does not forget information.

Again, if you ignore the mathematical subtleties (which you shouldn't after you have become comfortable with the basic concepts!), these maps are actually inverses of each other, and thus show that there is no difference in the information encoded in $\mathcal{H}_{1D}$ and $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$.

What about operators? Let me just exemplify this for the position operator $\hat x$. The scalar product of $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$ is given by

$$ (\psi,\phi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\bar\psi(x)\mathrm{d}x\forall \phi, \psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$$

and the defining property of the position operator is that $\hat x |x\rangle = x|x\rangle$, and so applying the map $\mathrm{Func}$ to it yields $\langle \psi | \hat x | x\rangle = x \langle \psi | x \rangle$, which immediately yields $\mathrm{Func}(\hat x | x \rangle) = x \mathrm{Func}(|x\rangle)$ and means that representing $\hat x$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$ is nothing more that multiplying a function $\psi$ by the identity function $id_\mathbb{R}(x) = x$.

Comment: Why are elements of a Hilbert space called "vectors" anyway?  Can't we just call them elements?  It seems kind of confusing to say a function is a type of vector.  The word "vector" has always had the connotation of being a list of elements (at least in high school, undergrad, and grad school engineering courses), rather than an element itself...

Comment: A vector is just an element of a set that fulfills the axioms of being a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition)

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding how $\psi = \psi(x)$ can both be the vector $|\psi\rangle$ **and** a coefficient in the basis expansion of the same vector, i.e. how can it be that $$|\psi\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |x\rangle\langle x|\psi\rangle \,\mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi(x) |x\rangle \,\mathrm{d}x \stackrel{?}{=} \psi(x)?$$ Or am I misunderstanding anything?

Comment: You are indeed misunderstanding something. $|\psi\rangle$ is *not* literally the same as $\psi(x)$, the two are related by $\psi(x) = \langle x|\psi\rangle$, which is a bijection (a Hilbert space isomorphism, to be precise) between the abstract space $\mathcal{H}$ where $|\psi\rangle$ lives and the concrete space $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$ where $\psi(x)$ lives. Both spaces are Hilbert spaces, and both objects are vectors (as elements of their respective spaces), but they are *not equal*, they just encode the same information in two different ways.

Comment: (This is the "usual" story as presented by many textbooks and lectures. As mentioned in the other answers, the map $\psi(x) = \langle x | \psi \rangle$ is not really a bijection, since it can produce things that are not functions but distributions, but this is not relevant to the problem you seem to have)

Comment: But how can you be sure you aren't you losing information by projecting $|\psi\rangle$ on some vector $|x\rangle$? Is it because by $|x\rangle$, we do not mean one specific $x$, but rather any of the possible values (i.e. $|x\rangle$ is variable)?

...

Comment: Now, if I understood this correctly, since the abstract $|\psi\rangle$ is not literally the same as $\psi(x)$, wouldn't the abstract operator $\hat{p}$ also not literally be the same as the $\hat{p} = -i\hbar \partial_x$ which operates on the concrete space $L^2(\mathbb{R, C})$? I'm confused because we say it's the same operator, but mathematically it seems that it isn't (it operates on different things).

Comment: I have edited the body of my answer to (hopefully) answer your questions more accurately.

Comment: So the operator "in position space" is indeed equivalent to the operator on $\mathcal{H}$, but they're not the same mathematical object. I think my mind is finally satisfied with this explanation, thank you very much!

One last thing: In the last paragraph, I don't see where the $\langle\psi|\hat{x}|x\rangle = x\langle\psi|x\rangle$ is coming from - wasn't the function returned by $\mathrm{Func}$ equal to $x \mapsto \langle x|\psi\rangle$? Where does the $\psi$ on the left side come from?

Comment: Shortly after I had written that, I thought this might be not the best way to put it, but using $\langle \psi | x \rangle = \langle x | \psi \rangle ^*$, where $*$ is complex conjugation makes it irrelevant whether we put the $\psi$ on the left and $x$ on the right or vice versa, and since the value $x$ is real, $x^* = x$, which then leads to my statement about $\mathrm{Func}$.

Comment: I have a question on the same. $|\psi\rangle =\int dx \psi(x) |x\rangle$, one has $\hat{P}|\psi\rangle = -i\hbar \int dx (\partial_x \psi(x)) |x\rangle$. Given this, how does $\hat{X}|x\rangle\langle x|\hat{P}$ and $\hat{P}|x\rangle\langle x|\hat{X}$ differ where $\hat{X}$ is the position operator? Can you please give me the expressions for both? The action of $\hat{X}\hat{P}$ and $\hat{P}\hat{X}$ differ because of commutativity, but how the action of one operator on the ket and the other on the bra and vice-versa differ is confusing to me. Kindly explain.

Answer (score 14):

I really appreciate this question. You are perfectly right and your confusion is understandable. Sadly, the physics world is somewhat sloppy in their use of notation at times.

Of course, when writing $P\psi(x)$ one does not intent to apply the operator to a scalar, but the $P$ is applied to the ket vector $\psi$.

But now comes the major source of confusion, IMO. While to you the wave function really is just

> the coefficients of a state vector when the vector is written in a particular basis

and the state vector is element of some abstract Hilbert space, many people will argue that the Hilbert space is actually a function space. Which one precisely depends on the system under consideration but specifically for a free particle it'll be $L^2(\mathbb R,\mathbb C)$, i.e. the space of square-integrable function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C$. So in this space, the actual function $\psi$ is the vector. That space is linear (a.k.a. a vector space) and it also has a scalar product, defined via the integral. It is also *complete* which means that one can insert identities as you did above. That's actually what a Hilbert space is (to a mathematician): a complete vector space with a scalar product.

When taking on this view, it is legitimate to apply an operator to a function. Indeed, only now does the identification $P=-i\hbar\partial_x$ make any sense. It is a differential operator which can be applied to functions.

The advantage of the Dirac bra-ket-notation is that it allows you to step back from any concrete realizations of the underlying Hilbert space. This has some advantages:

- The analogy to linear algebra is more pronounced.
- Many general ideas which arise in quantum theory can be formulated independent of the system under investigation. In particular, the formalism is the same for infinite-dimensional Hilbert space like the $L^2$ and finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces like $\mathbb C^2$, the spin-1/2 space.
- Change of basis is very transparent. Specifically the connection of position and momentum space via the Fourier transform comes about naturally.

So why should we bother working in function spaces?

- It leads to differential equations which have a well-understood theory.
- There are some mathematical subtleties$^1$ involved when dealing with infinite-dimensional spaces. Those can best be understood in function spaces.
- Often we need to leave the blessed world of Hilbert spaces and go beyond that. The space is then no longer complete. Delta functions are such an example. They are certainly not square integrable, hell, the square of a delta function is not even defined. In won't go into depth here. The phrase you need to search for is *Gelfand space triplet*.

---

$^1$ For an overview of what can go terribly wrong in quantum mechanics upon getting to comfortable with Dirac's notation, I recommend this excellent article: [F. Gieres, *Mathematical surprises and Dirac's formalism in quantum mechanics*, arXiv:quant-ph/9907069](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9907069)

---

***Edit*** in response to @Jyothi's comment:

The action of the momentum operator as a derivative may be written as $\langle x|\hat P|\psi\rangle = -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\langle x|\psi\rangle$.

Now, consider the following calculation of the action of the operator product $\hat P\hat X$:

$$
\langle x|\hat P\hat X|\psi\rangle = \int\mathrm dx'\,\langle x|\hat P\hat X|x'\rangle\langle x'|\psi\rangle = \int\mathrm dx'\,x'\langle x|\hat P|x'\rangle\langle x'|\psi\rangle\\
= -i\hbar\int\mathrm dx'\,x'\psi(x')\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta(x-x')\\
= +i\hbar\int\mathrm dx'\,x'\psi(x')\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}\delta(x-x')\\
=-i\hbar\int\mathrm dx'\,\delta(x-x')\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}(x'\psi(x'))\\
=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x\psi(x))\\
= -i\hbar\Bigl(\psi(x)+x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\psi(x)\Bigr)\\
=-i\hbar\langle x|\psi\rangle + x\langle x|\hat P|\psi\rangle\\
=-i\hbar\langle x|\psi\rangle + \langle x|\hat X\hat P|\psi\rangle\\
=\langle x|(-i\hbar+\hat X\hat P)|\psi\rangle.
$$
In the third line, I rewrote a derivative for $x$ as an derivative for $x'$, yielding a minus sign. In the step after, integration by parts was used, arguing that the boundary terms vanish at $\pm\infty$. By assuming this holds for general $|\psi\rangle$, one can equate the operators on the LHS and RHS, giving $\hat P\hat X=-i\hbar+\hat X\hat P$ or $[\hat X,\hat P]=i\hbar$.

This "calculation" is severely handwavy, *none* of it is mathematically rigorous. For example, I'm taking derivatives of $\delta$ which is not defined. But I believe the gist of this calculation could be made rigorous in a distributional sense. Also, in my mind the commutator is actually more fundamental and this, if anything, shows that the wave function representation is compatible with that.

Comment: "So in this space, the actual function ψ is the vector."  
I'm having some trouble understanding this. I know that the function space L² is an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space and that a function can be interpreted as an element of such a space, but how exactly is it done? Does this mean that ψ is identified as ψ(x) = |ψ⟩? That can't be it - ψ(x) = ⟨x|ψ⟩, not ψ(x) = |ψ⟩. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: The bra-ket notation is literally defining an inner product on whatever underlying vector space is being used, i.e. $\langle x | \psi(x) \rangle$ is the inner product of the vector $x$ and $\psi(x)$.  The individual notation is useful when using operators (look into some Functional Analysis, Riesz Rep. Thm).  For vectors, the bras and kets represent the same objects, but for operators they have a different meaning (because of the Riesz Thm), so that is where they become useful.

Comment: @Socob in your statement $\psi(x)=|\psi\rangle$ the $\psi(x)$ is used as a _function_ $\psi\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ instead of a _value of this function_ $\psi|_x$. It's just abuse of notation. One should instead have written just $\psi$ not $\psi(x)$.

Comment: @daaxix Okay, but how does one actually evaluate the inner product $\langle x | \psi \rangle$? If $|\psi \rangle = \psi$ and with the inner product on $L^2$, that would mean to me that $\langle x | \psi \rangle$ = $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x \psi(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$, which isn't the same as $\psi(x)$.

Comment: $|x_0\rangle$ designates the eigenstate of the position operator with eigenvalue $x_0$. This is given by a $\delta$ function centered at $x_0$, i.e. the wave function is $\delta_{x_0}(x)=\langle x|x_0\rangle=\delta(x-x_0)$.

Comment: So the inner product is obtained as:
$\langle x|\psi\rangle=\int\mathrm dx'\langle x|x'\rangle\langle x'|\psi\rangle=\int\mathrm dx'\delta(x-x')\psi(x') = \psi(x)$.

Comment: A mathematician would shoot me for that and he'd be right in doing so. $\delta$ is not even in the Hilbertspace, so one can hardly insert an identity via the completeness relation. In fact, the position operator does not even have any eigenvalues or eigenvectors. But if you are new to this, don't bother. Just read the paper I linked in the answer in 1--3 years.

Comment: @Socob, think of $\psi$ like some object in some space, maybe a spiky ball or something in 3-d.  Then yes $\langle x | \psi \rangle$ is the scaler part of the *projection* onto the $x$-axis.  This is a really poor part of the bra-ket notation and the subsequent abuse by physicists, really it should be more like $\psi(x) = \langle x | \psi \rangle | x \rangle$.  I learned this stuff coming from math and it drove me crazy too...

Comment: And math has already fleshed out all the theory needed in functional analysis in Hilbert and Banach spaces in a rigorous way so it isn't as if it needs to be reinvented...it has already been done in math...

Comment: @daaxix, I don't think $\psi(x)=\langle x|\psi\rangle|x\rangle$ is correct. LHS is a scalar, RHS is a "ket", function or not. It's really just $\psi(x)=\langle x|\psi\rangle$, period. Also, while I agree that the mathematics has been largely figured out, it goes a little bit behind your standard functional analysis course. You'll at least have to introduce tempered distributions and their way of adding to the Hilbert space (the [Gelfand space triple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space)) to describe position eigenstates properly.

Comment: @Jonas, mathematically this is incorrect, even tempered distributions map functions to a set of real numbers through the inner product notation (not other functions like $\psi(x)$!  Tempered distributions extend linear functionals in a mathematically consistent way, so that the inner product gives numbers, not functions.  If you want functions as output then you have to go to somthing like a convolution... Please, specifically show how $\psi(x)$ is a scalar in any sense of the definition...it isn't $\psi(0)$ or $\psi(x_0)$ for some specific $x_0$...scalar valued fnc $\ne$ scalar.

Comment: I guess we just have a misunderstanding regarding notation. By $\psi(x)$ is meant the evaluation of the function $\psi$ at concrete $x$. This is clearly a scalar.

Comment: @Jonas I don't see how that "evaluation" of the inner product shows anything, since at the second equals sign, you already use $\langle x'|\psi\rangle = \psi(x')$ - but you're trying to show $\langle x|\psi\rangle = \psi(x)$. Isn't that circular?

Comment: Some might call it *circular*, some may call it *consistent*. You cannot prove anything really, it's more a matter of definition, but at least those definitions do not lead to contradictions as suspected by yourself.

Comment: @Jonas you say the position operator doesn't have any eigenvectors. We then could also say that neither momentum operator, nor free particle Hamiltonian have any eigenstates. Bah, plane wave expansion is messed up!

Comment: @Ruslan, yes that's right, there are no *proper* eigenvalues/-vectors in the normal Hilbert space. However, when extending the search to the [rigged Hilbert space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space) there are *generalized* eigenfunctions, or rather eigendistributions, the $\delta$s we all know and love and you can do the plane wave expansion again.

Comment: I have a question on the same. $|\psi\rangle =\int dx \psi(x) |x\rangle$, one has $\hat{P}|\psi\rangle = -i\hbar \int dx (\partial_x \psi(x)) |x\rangle$. Given this, how does $\hat{X}|x\rangle\langle x|\hat{P}$ and $\hat{P}|x\rangle\langle x|\hat{X}$ differ where $\hat{X}$ is the position operator? Can you please give me the expressions for both? The action of $\hat{X}\hat{P}$ and $\hat{P}\hat{X}$ differ because of commutativity, but how the action of one operator on the ket and the other on the bra and vice-versa differ is confusing to me. Kindly explain.

Comment: @Jyothi I amended my answer with a calculation that "derives" the commutator $[\hat X,\hat P]$ from the action of the operators in the wave function representation. Hope that helps clear up any confusion.

Comment: Thanks  a lot. But still something is confusing. If I have a density matrix of the form $\rho = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx |x\rangle\langle x|$, what is $\hat{X}\rho\hat{P}$ and $\hat{P}\rho\hat{X}$ .It would be great if you could outline it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the rigor. It's fine as is. Distributions have derivatives too. The delta function $δ(x)$ is the distribution which, when applied to a function $f$ yields $\int f(x) δ(x) dx = f(0)$. Its derivative $δ'(x)$ is defined as the distribution which yields $\int f(x) δ'(x) dx = -\int f'(x) δ(x) dx = -f'(0)$. It's all standard material that you can easily find references for. Here's one: [Distributions And Distributional Derivatives](https://www.math.arizona.edu/~kglasner/math456/GREENS1.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

To make it completely foolproof<sup>1</sup>, you'd need to define the operators via their eigenbasis:
$$
  P|\psi\rangle = \int_\mathbb{R}\!\!\mathrm{d}p\ (p\cdot|p\rangle\langle p|\psi\rangle)
$$
where <sub>(proportionality $\propto$ means, you'd still need to normalise the Fourier transform)</sub>
$$
  |p\rangle \propto \int_\mathbb{R}\!\!\mathrm{d}x\ e^{-i(p/\hslash)x} |x\rangle.
$$

But because $P$ (like most anything you'll find operating on the Hilbert spaces of quantum-mechanics) is a *linear operator*, it isn't really necessary to give such a "proper definition" of the *function* $P : \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$. Instead, you can just define the result by giving all the possible *scalar products*<sup>2</sup>:
$$
  \langle x|P|\psi\rangle
= -i\hslash \frac{\partial \psi(x)}{\partial x}
= -i\hslash \frac{\partial \langle x|\psi\rangle}{\partial x}.
$$
This is, by means of partial integration<sup>3</sup>, equivalent to the other definition:
$$\begin{align}
 \int_\mathbb{R}\!\!\mathrm{d}p\ (p\cdot\langle x|p\rangle\langle p|\psi\rangle)
   \propto& \int_\mathbb{R}\!\!\mathrm{d}p
       \int_\mathbb{R}\!\!\mathrm{d}x'\!
        \int_\mathbb{R}\!\!\mathrm{d}x''
         \ p\cdot e^{-i(p/\hslash)(x'-x'')} \langle x|x''\rangle \langle x'|\psi\rangle
 \\=& \int_\mathbb{R}\!\!\mathrm{d}p
       \int_\mathbb{R}\!\!\mathrm{d}x'
         \ p\cdot e^{-i(p/\hslash)(x'-x)} \langle x'|\psi\rangle
 \\=& \int_\mathbb{R}\!\!\mathrm{d}p\ (i\hslash)
       \int_\mathbb{R}\!\!\mathrm{d}x'
         \ (\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x'} e^{-i(p/\hslash)(x'-x)}) \langle x'|\psi\rangle
 \\=& -i\hslash\int_\mathbb{R}\!\!\mathrm{d}p
       \int_\mathbb{R}\!\!\mathrm{d}x'
         \ e^{-i(p/\hslash)(x'-x)} (\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x'} \langle x'|\psi\rangle)
 \\\propto& -i\hslash \frac{\partial \langle x | \psi \rangle}{\partial x}.
\end{align}$$

Simply writing $P = -i\hslash \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is a pretty natural shorthand for the scalar product definition.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Actually, I've still been using sloppy notation there: $|x\rangle$ and $|p\rangle$ mean different things though both $x$ and $p$ are merely arbitrary integration-variable names... but alas, that's what physicist do all the time. *Really strictly speaking*, we'd need to write something like $|\mathrm{loc}_x\rangle$ and $|\mathrm{mom}_p\rangle$ for these eigenstates.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>I.e. you're basically defining the dyadic function $P: \mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}^\ast \to \mathbb{C}$.</sub>

<sup>3</sup><sub>When working in an unbounded space (often also when we aren't...) we ignore boundary terms.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

As said in @AlfredCentauri 's comment, you have to think as $|\psi\rangle$ as a complex vector, let us write is $\vec \psi$.

$|x\rangle$ is representing one element of a  basis, so let us write it $\vec e_x$. 
Like any vector, we can decompose $\vec \psi$ on the $\vec e_x$ basis : 
$$\vec \psi = \sum \psi_x \vec e_x$$

$\psi_x$ is the component of the vector $\vec\psi$ on the $\vec e_x$ axis, and you have simply : $$\psi_x = \psi(x) = \langle x|\psi\rangle = (\vec e_x)^\star.\vec \psi \tag{1}$$

$A$ is an operator (say a matrix) applying on the vector $\vec \psi$, so $(A\psi)(x)$ is simply $(A\psi)_x$, the component of the vector $A\vec \psi$, on the $\vec e_x$ axis, and you may write it, applying (1) to the vector $A\vec \psi$ instead of $\vec \psi$:

$$(A\psi)_x = (A\psi)(x)=\langle x|A\psi\rangle= (\vec e_x)^\star. (A\vec \psi) \tag{2}$$

Comment: "Like any vector, we can decompose..." well, yeah. Though it should be noted that all this holds on far less obvious grounds than physicists like to pretend. Vectors in _general vector spaces_, or general Hilbert spaces, may allow no basis expansion.

Comment: Okay, so $|\psi\rangle = \vec{\psi} = \psi$?

Looking at your equation (2), I can't help but think that the example from Wikipedia which I quoted above is incorrect, since

$$A \psi(x)
= (A \psi)(x)
= (A|\psi\rangle)(x)
= \langle x|(A|\psi\rangle)
= \langle x | A | \psi \rangle
\ne A \langle x | \psi \rangle$$

That last expression doesn't make mathematical sense to me to begin with. Am I correct with this or have I misunderstood anything?

Comment: @Socob : Yes, the correspondance is  $|\psi\rangle = \vec \psi$, while I write $\psi_x$ as the component of $\vec \psi$ on the $\vec e_x$ axis. Wikepedia is correct. $A\langle x|\psi\rangle$ is meaningful. For instance, if $A$ is the momentum operator, this means $P\langle x|\psi\rangle = -i\hbar {\partial_x}\, \psi(x)$. The subtelty is that operators may have different representations. Applying to the vector $|\psi\rangle$, you may consider an operator like an (infinite) matrix. However, applying to a function of $x$, like $\psi(x)$, the representation of this operator depends on $x$,

Comment: @Socob .... in the case of the momentum operator, the representation is the differential operator $-i\hbar {\partial_x}$. The equality $\langle x|A|\psi\rangle=A\langle x|\psi\rangle$ could be rewritten, with my notations : $(A\psi)_x = A (\psi_x)$.  Here $(A\psi)_x$ and $\psi_x$ are respectively the components of the vectors $ A \vec\psi$ and $\vec \psi$ on the axis $\vec e_x$, and, by consequence, are functions of $x$. So the operator $A$, in this representation, makes a relation between $2$ functions of $x$.

Comment: @Socob : ...So the representation of $A$ here necessarily depends on $x$, for instance, for the momentum operator $P$, it is a differential operator.

Comment: This is all very helpful and sounds plausible, but the one thing I still don't understand or have a hard time accepting is how $(A\psi)_x = A(\psi_x)$ could possibly work. On the LHS, $A$ maps the vector $\psi$ to another vector and we take the $x$-component of that vector. On the RHS, $A$ somehow maps the scalar $\psi_x$ to another scalar. 


How can that work? If $A$ maps a vector to another vector, that can't possibly be the same operator $A$ on both sides. I can accept that they're "equivalent" in some way, I don't see how we'd be able to say that it's the **same** operator both times.

Comment: @Socob : This is the illustation that an operator $A$ has  different representations, depending on the objects upon which this operators acts. One could write, if you prefer : $(A_{rep1}\psi)_x = A_{rep2}(\psi_x)$, where $A_{rep1}$ and $A_{rep2}$ are $2$ different reprentations of the operator $A$, acting respectively on a (Hilbert space) vector, and a function of $x$

Comment: I have a question on the same. $|\psi\rangle =\int dx \psi(x) |x\rangle$, one has $\hat{P}|\psi\rangle = -i\hbar \int dx (\partial_x \psi(x)) |x\rangle$. Given this, how does $\hat{X}|x\rangle\langle x|\hat{P}$ and $\hat{P}|x\rangle\langle x|\hat{X}$ differ where $\hat{X}$ is the position operator? Can you please give me the expressions for both? The action of $\hat{X}\hat{P}$ and $\hat{P}\hat{X}$ differ because of commutativity, but how the action of one operator on the ket and the other on the bra and vice-versa differ is confusing to me. Kindly explain.